# Why my event handler do not fired?

Tags: server

I want to build an event handle to limit user to upload file to SharePoint list or Library and than shows an error message.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
        properties.ErrorMessage = "you cannot upload any file!";
        properties.Cancel = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
    }
}
```

the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/LibraryA">    // or <Receivers ListTemplateId="101"> for global libary
    <Receiver>
        <Name>EventReceiver1ItemAdding</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>eventhandle.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

I choose list item events in what type... box and Document Library in what item... box

result:
upload file success :(

Comment: you want to cancel the upload?

Comment: @RaghavendraC yes! but i cannot cancel it

Comment: I have try to set it global!  `<Receivers ListTemplateId="101">` but it doesn't work

Comment: did below answer worked?

Answer (score 0):

Hi place below code in the beggining of the ItemAdding method may be this is causing issue.

```
base.ItemAdding(properties);
```

if you place this it might work, modified code may look like this.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdding(properties);
    try
    {
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
        properties.ErrorMessage = "you cannot upload any file!";
        properties.Cancel = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
    }
}
```

sience you are canceling with error then page may stop uploading and show sommthing like **An application error occurred on the server**